# How to get a method code that knows when user exit Apps

Tags: android, exit, logout, session-timeout, onresume

Issue at hand:

I would like to know if there are any method codes that is specifically used to detect or log when user pushes the app to the background by exiting the app or calling a different app. 
I have written this code, thinking that it can be used when the user exits the entire app.

However, the sectInt value is logged after each activity within the app has been closed. And when I enter the PropertyActivity after a stipulated time greater than inactivity_Timeout, it will log me out. This is not what I want, I would like the sectInt to actually function and logout when I exit the app instead of each individual activity within the app. Any coding suggestions?

The code below:

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    //get the current time on exit
    curDate = new Date();
    Log.i("RootActivity:onStop()","******curDate=******"+curDate);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setloginButton();
    EnquiryActivity.PROPERTY = 0;
    //EDITED FOR SESSION LOGOUT
    //Get the Resume Time
    resumeDate = new Date();
    Log.i("RootActivity:onResume()","******resumeDate=******"+resumeDate);
    long diff = resumeDate.getTime() - curDate.getTime();
    long secInt = diff / 1000 % 60; //conversion of milliseconds into human readable form
    Log.i("RootActivity:onResume()","******sectInt=******"+secInt);
    if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){// SET EXIT SCREEN INTERVAL LOGOUT
        IdleLogout();
    }   
}
```

and this is the idle logout method.

```
 public void IdleLogout(){
    Log.i("RootActivity:IdleLogout()","******APP LOGGEDOUT******");
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE);             
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.clear();     // CLEAR ALL FILEDS
    editor.commit();    // COMMIT CHANGES 
    setloginButton();   // Change logout button to login
    RootActivity.alertDialog(RootActivity.this,getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)).create().show();
    ////Return page to PROPERTYACTIVITY with alertdialog.   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have edited and changed the codings such that it actually performs an auto logout based on inactivity rather than an app logout when it is pushed to the background.

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
     super.onStop();
     //Timer needs to be stopped when user manually pressed BACK button
     stopDisconnectTimer();
}

@Override
protected  void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setloginButton();
    EnquiryActivity.PROPERTY = 0;
    curDate = new Date();
    Log.i("RootActivity:onResume()","******curDate=******"+curDate);
    resetDisconnectTimer(); 
}

//METHOD USED FOR INACTIVITY LOGOUT
public static class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    public static Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){ 
        }
    };
}

private Runnable disconnectCallback= new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Get the Resume Time & get difference in Time for Logout
        resumeDate = new Date();
        Log.i("RootActivity:onRun()","******resumeDate=******"+resumeDate);
        long diff = resumeDate.getTime() - curDate.getTime();
        long secInt = diff / 1000 % 60; //conversion of milliseconds into human readable form
        Log.i("RootActivity:onRun()","******sectInt=******"+secInt);
        if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){// SET EXIT SCREEN INTERVAL LOGOUT
        IdleLogout();
        }   
    }
};

//METHOD TO CALL ON RESETDISCONNECT WHEN USER ACTIVITY RESUMES
public void resetDisconnectTimer(){
    MyBaseActivity.disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    MyBaseActivity.disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, Inactivity_Timeout);
}

//METHOD TO CALL ON STOPDISCONNECT WHEN USER PRESS BACK BUTTON
public void stopDisconnectTimer(){
    MyBaseActivity.disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
}
```

Comment: i upvote you because of your hard efforts.. and couldnt reply because my pc is jamed.. and lokin at ur solution, dat was the logic bt in diff perspective catchin onPause and onResume..bt great work..

Answer (score 0):

Fragments Activities Services  ... have their life cycle . Here is the tutorial for activity lifecycle   http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

Comment: I believe I am already utilising the fragments activities services.